# what is the logical error in the following lru code

Tags: c++, caching, struct, lru

I wanted to use the following code for a very simple lru page replacement for my application. The **counter** for the second and third elements of **buf_rec** always have the same values and I couldn't see why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct search_cache_rec
    {
        int index;
        int counter;
    }search_cache_rec;
search_cache_rec buf_rec[3];
void inint_buf()
{
    for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
    {
        buf_rec[m].index=-1;
        buf_rec[m].counter=100;
    }
}
int i,j,fs[3];
int ind,k,l,flag1=0,flag2=0,pf=0,frsize=3;

bool search_cache(int *id)
{
    bool status=false;
    flag1=0,flag2=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(buf_rec[i].index==*id)
        {
            flag1=1;
            flag2=1;
            *tanker_id=i;
            buf_rec[i].counter+=2;
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                        //if(buf_rec[i].counter>-1)
                    buf_rec[i].counter--;
                }
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(flag1==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if(buf_rec[i].index==-1)
            {
                buf_rec[i].index=*id;
                flag2=1;
                *tanker_id=i;
                buf_rec[i].counter+=2;
                for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                        //if(buf_rec[i].counter>-1)
                    buf_rec[i].counter--;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag2==0)
    {
        int min=buf_rec[0].counter;

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if(min>buf_rec[i].counter)
            {
                min=buf_rec[i].counter;
                ind=i;
            }
        }
        buf_rec[ind].index=*id;
        buf_rec[i].counter+=2;
        *id=i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                //if(buf_rec[i].counter>-1)
            buf_rec[i].counter--;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
  void display()
    {
        int i;
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            printf("\t%d",buf_rec[i].index);
    }
```

here is how i use it

```
#include"lru.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>


void main()
{
    int num;
    inint_buf();
    display();
    std::cout<<"\nEnter a num\n";
    std::cin>>num;
    while(num!=-1)
    {
        search_cache(&num);
        display();
        std::cout<<"\nEnter a num\n";
        std::cin>>num;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. You might be better off on code reviews.

Comment: @MarkB: I thought it would make it simpler to spot the problem

Comment: Why so many global variables ? Perhaps also consider giving your variables meaningful names, and add some comments ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that you are using the global variable `i` in two nested for loops in a few places which will result in the outer loop being finished prematurely. You almost always want to use different loop variables for nested loops.

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if(buf_rec[i].index==*id)
    {
        flag1=1;
        flag2=1;
        *tanker_id=i;
        buf_rec[i].counter+=2;

        for(j=0;j<3;j++)  //Note change from i to j
        {
            buf_rec[j].counter--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would also suggest not using globals for loop variables but instead prefer something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
}
```

unless you are still using some old compilers (VC6 for example has an issue with this form of variable definition).

Comment: Actually, this mistake doesn't change anything unless there are duplicate entries in the LRU array. Copy-pasting your code and fixing an omission of the `tanker_id` variable appears to result in expected behavior (I modified `display()` to output the count of each element). What, exactly, is not working for you?

Comment: have you tried it with at least 6 numbers with some repetitions? it does not do lru as it should be

Comment: I played around with it quickly and it always seems to replace the  LRU with a new entry. If you can give me a series of inputs that replicates it not working let me know.

Comment: i have fixed my problem. But i can give you the inputs if you still want it. But i definitely got a different and correct result with the code i put as answer. You can take a look at my answer.

Comment: Yup, I saw I understand your issue better now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but in

```
if( flag2 == 0)
```

you need to initialize ind.

```
ind = 0;
```

In the same if block after the first for loop 
I think

```
buf_rec[i].counter+=2;
```

should be

```
buf_rec[ind].counter+=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is `int ind` a global variable?

I think it needs to be an (initialized) local variable in the `if(flag2==0)` clause.

This is one of many reasons why global variables are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using time() function to initialize and control the counter variable afterwards . 
Here is the final code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct search_buf_rec
    {
        int index;
        time_t counter;
    }search_buf_rec;
search_buf_rec buf_rec[3];
void inint_buf()
{
    for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
    {
        buf_rec[m].index=-1;
        buf_rec[m].counter=time(NULL);
    }
}

int i,flag1=0,flag2=0;

bool search_ht_cache(int *id)
{
    flag1=0,flag2=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(buf_rec[i].index==*id)
        {
            flag1=1;
            flag2=1;
            *id=i;
            buf_rec[i].counter=time(NULL);

            return true;
        }
    }

    if(flag1==0)
    {
        int ind=0;
        time_t min=buf_rec[0].counter;

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if(min>buf_rec[i].counter)
            {
                min=buf_rec[i].counter;
                ind=i;
            }
        }
        buf_rec[ind].index=*id;
        buf_rec[ind].counter=time(NULL);
        *id=i;

        return false;
    }


}
```